# one of its monitors

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "one of its monitors" refer to "one of the monitors (of the Secretary of State's Office)"? Or refer to "one of the party monitors"?

> 11Alive was able to determine that this part is true. The media and **the party monitors** were not given notice that counting would continue into the early morning hours and they should have been.

> The Secretary of State's Office said **one of its monitors** was present. The counting of those heavily-Democratic absentee ballots did result in a big batch of numbers coming from Fulton County in the 1 a.m. am hour on election night.

> Source: [FACT-CHECKING CLAIMS ABOUT FULTON COUNTY'S ELECTION | THESE 'SUITCASES' ARE ACTUALLY BALLOT CONTAINERS](http://Source:%20FACT-CHECKING%20CLAIMS%20ABOUT%20FULTON%20COUNTY%27S%20ELECTION%20%7C%20THESE%20%27SUITCASES%27%20ARE%20ACTUALLY%20BALLOT%20CONTAINERS)

Comment: "The Secretary of State's Office said one of its monitors was present." One of the Secretary of State's monitors was present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally ambiguous (as most pronouns are) but there are plenty of clues that point to "the Secretary of State's monitors".

The closest relevant noun is "The Secretary of State's Office", pronouns usually refer to a close noun.  We know that there are multiple parties in the USA, so "it's" would not usually refer to "The Democrats and the Republicans".  And we know that the party monitors went home (this is the whole point of the article) so we know that the party monitors were *not* present.

Thus there is only one reasonable interpretation.